# How can I get the private IP put into conf file ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have this role task file in `roles/make_elasticsearch_conf/tasks/main.yml`:

```yaml
---
# tasks file for make_elasticsearch_conf
#

- name: Get private IP address
  command:
    cmd: "hostname -I | awk '{print $2}'"
  register: "cluster_ip"

- name: Create /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml File
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: elasticsearch.yml.j2
    dest: /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
```

I also have a template in `roles/make_elasticsearch_conf/templates/elasticsearch.yml.j2`:

```
cluster.name: {{ ansible_host }}
node.name: {{ ansible_host }}
network.host: {{ cluster_ip }}
```

I use it in this `make_elastic_search_conf.yml` playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Make Elastic Search Config.
  hosts: all
  become: True
  gather_facts: True
  roles:
    - roles/make_elasticsearch_conf
```

When I run my playbook I get this error:

> FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["hostname", "-I", "|", "awk", "{print $2}"], "delta": "0:00:00.006257", "end": "2022-12-06 21:54:47.612238", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 255, "start": "2022-12-06 21:54:47.605981", "stderr": "Usage: hostname [-b] {hostname|-F file}         set host name (from file)\n       hostname [-a|-A|-d|-f|-i|-I|-s|-y]       display formatted name\n       hostname                                 display host name\n\n       {yp,nis,}domainname {nisdomain|-F file}  set NIS domain name (from file)\n       {yp,nis,}domainname                      display NIS domain name\n\n       dnsdomainname                            display dns domain name\n\n       hostname -V|--version|-h|--help          print info and exit\n\nProgram name:\n       {yp,nis,}domainname=hostname -y\n       dnsdomainname=hostname -d\n\nProgram options:\n    -a, --alias            alias names\n    -A, --all-fqdns        all long host names (FQDNs)\n    -b, --boot             set default hostname if none available\n    -d, --domain           DNS domain name\n    -f, --fqdn, --long     long host name (FQDN)\n    -F, --file             read host name or NIS domain name from given file\n    -i, --ip-address       addresses for the host name\n    -I, --all-ip-addresses all addresses for the host\n    -s, --short            short host name\n    -y, --yp, --nis        NIS/YP domain name\n\nDescription:\n   This command can get or set the host name or the NIS domain name. You can\n   also get the DNS domain or the FQDN (fully qualified domain name).\n   Unless you are using bind or NIS for host lookups you can change the\n   FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name) and the DNS domain name (which is\n   part of the FQDN) in the /etc/hosts file.", "stderr_lines": ["Usage: hostname [-b] {hostname|-F file}         set host name (from file)", "       hostname [-a|-A|-d|-f|-i|-I|-s|-y]       display formatted name", "       hostname                                 display host name", "", "       {yp,nis,}domainname {nisdomain|-F file}  set NIS domain name (from file)", "       {yp,nis,}domainname                      display NIS domain name", "", "       dnsdomainname                            display dns domain name", "", "       hostname -V|--version|-h|--help          print info and exit", "", "Program name:", "       {yp,nis,}domainname=hostname -y", "       dnsdomainname=hostname -d", "", "Program options:", "    -a, --alias            alias names", "    -A, --all-fqdns        all long host names (FQDNs)", "    -b, --boot             set default hostname if none available", "    -d, --domain           DNS domain name", "    -f, --fqdn, --long     long host name (FQDN)", "    -F, --file             read host name or NIS domain name from given file", "    -i, --ip-address       addresses for the host name", "    -I, --all-ip-addresses all addresses for the host", "    -s, --short            short host name", "    -y, --yp, --nis        NIS/YP domain name", "", "Description:", "   This command can get or set the host name or the NIS domain name. You can", "   also get the DNS domain or the FQDN (fully qualified domain name).", "   Unless you are using bind or NIS for host lookups you can change the", "   FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name) and the DNS domain name (which is", "   part of the FQDN) in the /etc/hosts file."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

I have tried all sorts of ways to get the private ip of the host but nothing I have tried gave the expected result.

Comment: Please note that this information is available in the node's gathered facts without needing to run a task in a shell on the target host (which is actually a bad practice in this specific case). See `ansible_all_ipv4_addresses`, `ansible_default_ipv4`, and all `ansible_<device_name>` variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by `|`.

As per the documentation of the command module:

> If you want to run a command through the shell (say you are using <,> >, |, and so on), you actually want the ansible.builtin.shell module instead. Parsing shell metacharacters can lead to unexpected commands
> being executed if quoting is not done correctly so it is more secure
> to use the command module when possible.

You might want to use `shell` module. Or better get the IP address from the ansible facts.